# 'He is able to speak English' ('be able to' is one chunk or can be stopped after 'he is able'?

Tags: to-infinitive

> 'He is able to speak English'

'to speak' is a to-infinitive usage? If so, 'to speak English' modifies 'able' as an adverb?

Or 'be able to' is one chunk unit to learn by heart as an idom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb phase is "**to be able** (*+ infinitive*)".

He **is able** *to speak* English.

- he = subject
- is able = conjugated verb phrase of "to be able"
- to speak = the infinitive
- English = direct object

There is no adverb.

The + infinitive part isn't required. "He is able" is a complete sentence. But if you're going to follow up with what he is able *to do* (infinitive), an infinitive must follow.

Comment: Thx. to infinitive has three usages: noun, adjective, adverb — which one here? (in case of "be able to infinitive"), for example, To speak English is ~.(noun usage as subject), Work hard to make money(usage as adverb(for purpose)), a book to read(as adjective)